# How do I store custom properties for OptionDialog options in IOS?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

In reviewing the documentation it seems as though you can only set the options property to a string array. When a user selects an option I need to know a numeric ID # associated with the string that's presented in the option dialog. How would I go about this if I can't pass in custom properties with each option?
This is for an iPad application.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the items you need based off if the index of the item selected

Answer (score 1):

You get the index as propertie of th click event, fired when clicking one of the Options

```
 var dialog = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog({
    options:['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
});
 dialog.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    switch (e.index) {
        case 0: //do something
               break;
        case 1: // Option 2
               break;
    }
});
```